# how do you convert this code to nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

So I have a list if vector4 values here [-4.571429, 12.142858, 0.35, 0.35] that need to be used as remapping values for a roughness texture i have. But here is the thing, my friend doesnt know nodes at all, only code. Vice versa for me. But he has given me this to attempt to turn it into a node group in the offchance i can get it worked out:

```
float remap_with_clamp(float remap_input, float min, float max, float zero, float one)

            {
                            vec2 xform = vec2(zero, one - zero);

                            float in_value = remap_input;
                            return clamp(xform.x + xform.y * in_value, min, max);
```

A note he also gave me is: "Your float zero and float one is the values like the -4, 12. The remap_input would be the image that is being remapped. The min and max is your clamp values. Another thing to mention this is all happening in multiple shader nodes as a float value at runtime we combine all 4 of the floats into a vec4 to save on code."

Any help i can get on this will definitely be appreciated

Comment: Quite a weird way of mapping .. (eg no need to take `zero` and `one` into a vector and out again, and with the values given, everything will come out at .35...)  Can you explain the 'Map Range' node to your friend?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very specific. However, converting code into nodes is precisely what the Dynamic Maths Expression / Node Expressions was made for (download it from https://github.com/baldingwizard/Blender-Addons/wiki/Dynamic-Maths-Expression).

Once you've installed the add-on you should have a new Maths Expression option in the node 'Add' menu.

Create a new text block and paste the following code :

```
outputs(output)

xform[] = combine(zero, one - zero)

in_value = remap_input
                            
output = combine(clip(xform[x] + xform[y] * in_value), clip(min), clip(max))
```

(NOTE: The above text is translated directly from your sample code, almost line for line)

Name the textblock something meaningful (eg, 'mycode'), go to the Node Editor and add a new Maths Expression with the text `TEXT:<name>` (replacing `<name>` with the name of your text block - eg, 'TEXT:mycode') and the add-on will interpret your code and generate a new node group containing the relevant nodes to implement the code.

Obviously your coder friend will need to produce code in the correct syntax for the add-on to interpret.

[image]

Comment: I think this works! Thanks for the help